# How to initialize a dynamic array of pointers to an object?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

```
class Leg
{
public:
  Leg (const char* const s  ,  const char* const e  , const double d) : startCity (s), endCity (e), distance (d) {}
  friend void outputLeg( ostream&  , const Leg& ) ;

private:
  const char* const startCity  ;
  const char* const endCity  ;
  const double distance;
};


class Route
{
public:

/* Include two public constructors --

(1) one to create a simple route consisting of only one leg,
The first constructor's only parameter should be a const reference to a Leg object.*/

  Route ( const Leg& ) : arrayHolder( new const Leg* [1]  ), arraySize( 1 ), r_distance( Leg.distance )  {}


//(2) another to create a new route by adding a leg to the end of an existing route.

private:

  const Leg** const arrayHolder;//save a dynamically-sized array of Leg*s as const Leg** const.
  const int arraySize;//save the size of the Leg* array as a const int .
  const double r_distance;//store the distance of the Route as a const double, computed as the sum of the distances of its Legs.
};
```

I could use some clarification on what I am doing in the first constructor. How do I correctly save the pointer of the passed Leg object?

Currently getting 'In constructor 'Route::Route(const Leg&)':
error: expected primary-expression before '.' token'

Answer (score 0):

Your error is clearly when trying to access Leg.distance. if distance is a static member of Leg, you need to access it by Leg::distance. But as you say that you want to create a one-Leg route, it seems that distance is a member variable, and you need actually to specify a parameter name in the function definition:

```
Route (const Leg& L) : arrayHolder( new const Leg* (&L)),
                       arraySize(1),
                       r_distance(L.distance) {}
```

Comment: Ahh I shouldve included the leg class, doing that now. The problem is distance is a private member. Is there a way to access it without making it public?

Comment: @Vic No, unless you do one of three things: - declare the class Route as friend, - add a getter function getDistance(), or - make distance public. The getter function is the recommended approach, of course

Answer (score -1):

I cannot see in your code what that 'distance' thing is, but you are using it on the class definition Leg so it only works if distance is a static variable. Didn't you mean to use the distance of the leg that is being passed? Like this:

```
Route ( const Leg& myLeg) : arrayHolder( new const Leg* [1]  ), arraySize( 1 ), r_distance( myLeg.distance )  {}
```

As for the pointer you are trying to store: you are passing it as a reference, so why not just store it as a reference as well? Something like this:

```
class Route
{
public:
    Route ( const Leg& myLeg ): theLeg( myLeg ) {}
private:
    const Leg& theLeg;
};
```

Comment: References must be initialized.

Comment: I initialise theLeg in the initialiser list. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Yes you did. But now it needs to be initialized in every constructor. What if some constructor does not have any Leg? btw the legs are supposed to be a collection in the OP's question.